# Need help making a check statement to make sure al the controls are not blank

Tags: c#

This is for a tic tac toe game. I need help making a check statement to see if all the controls' Texts are non-blank, and if they are, you have a draw (if someone had won the previous code would have discovered that). Can you give me a good example using my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
namespace MyGame
{
    public class Result1
    {


        static private int[,] Winners = new int[,]
                   {
                       // main gameplay Ex: if x is on 0,1,2 x is the winner
                        {0,1,2},
                        {3,4,5},
                        {6,7,8},
                        {0,3,6},
                        {1,4,7},
                        {2,5,8},
                        {0,4,8},
                        {2,4,6},
                   };


        static public bool CheckWinner(Button[] myControls)
        {
            //bolean statement to check for the winner 
            bool gameOver = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                int a = Winners[i, 0];
                int b = Winners[i, 1];
                int c = Winners[i, 2];

                Button b1 = myControls[a], b2 = myControls[b], b3 = myControls[c];
                if (b1.Text == "" || b2.Text == "" || b3.Text == "")
                    continue;

                if (b1.Text == b2.Text && b2.Text == b3.Text)
                {

                    b1.BackColor = b2.BackColor = b3.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
                    b1.Font = b2.Font = b3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 32F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic & System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
                    gameOver = true;
                    xWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
                    xWinnerForm.ShowDialog(); //only works with show not showDialog method gets overloaded  (b1.Text + " is the Winner"); to get around this I added and image showing the last player


                }


            }


        return gameOver;
       }





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that you already have code that will check for an empty space and that in all cases where you find an empty space there isn't a draw.  If you iterate through all possible spaces and haven't found a winner or an empty space, then it clearly is a draw.

```
static public bool CheckWinner(Button[] myControls)
{
    //bolean statement to check for the winner 
    bool gameOver = false;
    bool foundEmpty = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int a = Winners[i, 0];
        int b = Winners[i, 1];
        int c = Winners[i, 2];

        Button b1 = myControls[a], b2 = myControls[b], b3 = myControls[c];
        if (b1.Text == "" || b2.Text == "" || b3.Text == "")
        {
            foundEmpty = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (b1.Text == b2.Text && b2.Text == b3.Text)
        {

            b1.BackColor = b2.BackColor = b3.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
            b1.Font = b2.Font = b3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 32F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic & System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
            gameOver = true;
            xWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
            xWinnerForm.ShowDialog(); //only works with show not showDialog method gets overloaded  (b1.Text + " is the Winner"); to get around this I added and image showing the last player


        }


    }
    if (!gameOver && !foundEmpty)
    {
       // must be a draw
       gameOver = true;
    }

    return gameOver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of your controls are in the `myControls` array. You can use LINQ to query them rather easily:

```
if (myControls.All(c => c.Text != "") {
   // Draw
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it triggers the event when only 3 boxes are selected how can I resolve this. I am new to programming so I don,t really understand it that well yet